# Why sorted(dictionary) returns a list instead of dictionary?

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

```
{'goofy': '818-399-2763', 'mickey': '213-333-2341', 'minnie': '510-540-2390', 'donald': '415-638-4433'}
```

Above is a dictionary `phoneBook`. If I print the phoneBook, I'll get the whole dictionary as below shown

```
>>>print (phoneBook)
{'goofy': '818-399-2763', 'mickey': '213-333-2341', 'minnie': '510-540-2390', 'donald': '415-638-4433'}
```

But after I use sorted() on the dictionary `phoneBook` to sort its keys, and print the sorted dictionary, it doesn't return the whole dictionary with sorted keys, it returns a list containing all the keys instead.

```
>>>print (sorted(phoneBook))
['donald', 'goofy', 'mickey', 'minnie']
```

So my question is: isn't the sorted dictionary still a dictionary, except the sequence of the keys are changed? If so, shouldn't we get an output as below after we print the sorted(phoneBook)?

```
phoneBook = {'donald': '415-638-4433', 'goofy': '818-399-2763', 'mickey': '213-333-2341', 'minnie': '510-540-2390'}
```

Instead of the list of keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep in mind that dictionaries are *unordered*. So you can imagine what will happen if the dictionary got sorted and a dictionary was returned.

To sort the dictionary keys and values you should use:

```
sorted(phoneBook.items())
```

Calling an `iterator` on a dictionary will *naturally* return only its list of keys. `.items()` ensures both keys and values are returned.

To keep the order after sorting, put the resulting list of tuples (returned by `sorted`) in an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

phonebook_sorted = OrderedDict(sorted(phoneBook.items()))
```

Answer (score 3):

> isn't the sorted dictionary still a dictionary, except the sequence of the keys are changed?

No.  The builtin `sorted` function accepts an iterable as input and returns a list -- Always.

For a `dict`, iterating over it yields the keys and so `sorted` just sorts the keys.  If you want to sort the keys an values, then do:

```
sorted(phoneBook.items())
```

You'll still get a list, but it'll be a list of key-value pairs (as tuples).

Comment: Perhaps an important point too is that `sorted` expects an iterable ... that's all the information it gets (which is alluded to here by mentioning a dictionary iterates over keys)